# Life duration and space of stdout logs

Tags: docker, logging, console

I am using log4j. My log4j is configured to log functional logs to a graylog server. 
I am as well logging critical issues (like NPEs etc).
I would like to keep the rootLogger in DEBUG mode for application startup. However when my application has started I will continue to receive plenty of logs in my console. (I will deactivate file logging)

However I would like to know (I Googled my question but I did not find any answer to my question) what is the life duration of the logs in the console.

I know that if I kill my application they are lost and it is what I want. However I would like to know if it can cause memory and/or disk space issues if I keep my application up during 6 month.
Are they cleaned at a moment?

My application is in Docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [json-file logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#use-environment-variables-or-labels-with-logging-drivers) and running an application for several months, in my case, the log grew up to 20GB. So, the answer to your question is: No, logs are not cleaned while the container is running.

I added a [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) configuration to archive logs automatically.